# How to solve for x when x is found in both the exponent and multiplied to a term a (without using Lambert W function, if possible)

Tags: logarithms

We are currently discussing logarithms and exponential equations. I am currently answering a problem set until I stumbled upon this question:

$2(2^{2x})=4x+64$

I tried using the usual methods such as log and ln but I could not get past the $4x+64$. The best I was able to do was:

$(2x+1)\log (2) = \log (4x+64)$

If I tried solving the left side, I have:

$0.602x+0.3010 = \log(4x+64)$

If this is the right way, then I am stuck in this part of the equation. If I made a mistake in any of these steps, please let me know and please tell me how I can solve this question correctly. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean $2 \cdot 2^{2x} = 4x + 64$? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*2%5E%282x%29%3D4x%2B64) says the solution isn't nice at all.

Comment: It can be solved using Lambert w function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @VTand yes I tried searching the solution online and it was not pretty.

Comment: @RAHUL I was wondering if there was a solution without using Lambert W function, since we have not tackled that.

Comment: If you do not want to use the Lambert-W function, then the only way possible is to find an approximation of the solution using the secant or Newton or any other known algorithm. Note: you could simplify your equation by dividing both sides by 4, but this will not help.

Answer (score 1):

That equation can only be solved using Lambert $W$ function.
$$
2^{2x}=2x+32
$$
$$
(2x+32)2^{-2x} = 1
$$
$$
-(2x+32)2^{-2x-32}=-2^{-32}
$$
We know that we can represent $2$ as $e^{\ln2}$:
$$
-(2x+32)e^{-(2x+32)\ln2}=-2^{-32}\ \big |\cdot \ln 2
$$
$$
-(2x+32)\ln2\ e^{-(2x+32)\ln2}=-2^{-32}\ln 2
$$
Knowing that $W(xe^x)=x$:
$$
W(-(2x+32)\ln2\ e^{-(2x+32)\ln2})= -(2x+32)\ln2=W(-2^{-32}\ln2)
$$
Now it's easy to show that:
$$
x = -\cfrac{W(-2^{-32}\ln2)+32\ln2}{2\ln2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the positive zero of function
$$f(x)=2^{2x}-(2x+32)$$
only Lambert function can provide an explicit solution. Otherwise, numerical methods.

$f(x)$ is highly nonlinear. Consider instead function
$$g(x)=\log(2^{2x})-\log(2x+32)$$ which is close to linearity. Expand it as a Taylor series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=-5\log (2)+x \left(2 \log
   (2)-\frac{1}{16}\right)+\frac{x^2}{512}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic equation to get, as an *estimate*,
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(32-1024 \log (2)+\sqrt{10240 \log (2)+(1024 \log
   (2)-32)^2}\right)=2.60800$$ while the solution is $x=2.60896$.

For sure, we can do better
$$g(x)=-\log \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)+ \left(\log
   (4)-\frac{1}{18}\right)(x-2)+\frac{1}{648} (x-2)^2+O\left((x-2)^3\right)$$
Solve the quadratic equation to get, as another *estimate*, $x=2.60895$.